# OAuth 2 Refresh Token Implementation

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, refresh-token

I'm trying to figure out the proper flow and usage of Refresh Tokens with respect to the OAuth2 spec and I am completely stumped on how a specific use-case is supposed to work.

My main issue is, if I receive a refresh token from some OAuth provider (in this case Google), I have two problems I don't know how to solve:

1. How do I persist the refresh token securely so that it can be used to obtain new tokens to keep a user logged in?
2. How do I determine who the user is who needs a refresh token? I can't just have an endpoint that takes in old tokens or email addresses to issue a refreshed token because that seems incredibly dumb.

### [Quick image detailing oauth flow I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TskI.png)

---

I believe I am considering some small implementation details incorrectly and I just don't want my backend API to be open to some massive security hole if I can prevent it by asking the helpful people of StackOverflow how this is actually *supposed* to work.

I should add that the only solution that seems semi-plausible is using some sort of timed refresh mechanism but that would involve having access to the refresh-token on the frontend, which I am trying to avoid since that in itself seems like a security risk.

I am concerned about best practices here, so if my entire implementation is flawed and I should be doing X instead of Y or Z then I'm open to suggestions too.

Thanks for your time,

Ses

Comment: Check [this](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I persist the refresh token securely so that it can be used to obtain new tokens to keep a user logged in?

You can save the refresh token some place and just use it to get a new access token when ever you need to.

> How do I determine who the user is who needs a refresh token? I can't just have an endpoint that takes in old tokens or email addresses to issue a refreshed token because that seems incredibly dumb.

I think you are confusing authentication with authorization.

Oauth2 grants your application `authorization` to access a users data. When you use the refresh token there is no authentication involved there is no way to know who is preforming the action.  Oauth2 does not `authenticate` in any way that the user is preforming the action, oauth2 is your application preforming an action on the behalf of a user with their `authorization`. That does not ensure that the user is present when the action is preformed.

For that you would need to use [Openid connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) and use an id token to identify the user who is using your application.

Comment: This seems to answer my question, and after years of being confused by authorization vs. authentication, I think I now understand the difference more clearly.

Thank you very much--I'll look into implementing an Openid solution.

Comment: authentication is your birth certificate ,  authentication is your drivers licence